# Sniffing 3g network Pockethound

Tags: network, privacy, wifi

I was wondering if its possible to prevent 3g sniffing. Its not about the security of the information sent over 3g, but being able to use your 3g without anyone able to see traffic. There are machines that can detect any use of network nearby (Pockethound:http://www.bvsystems.com/Products/Security/PocketHound/pockethound.htm). I assume this machine uses something like a networkcard on monitoring mode. Is it possible to bypass machines like this?

Thanks in advance,

Michiel

Comment: Great, thx for the fast reply! Does this mean, if i change the frequency the device wont be able to detect me?

Comment: That particular device may not be able to detect you, but that doesn't mean you will be undetectable. Any device that is capable of listening on a frequency you're using can detect you. It's the nature of RF. Also, you probably will not be able to use your phone with any major carrier's cell tower if you do that.

Answer (score 3):

No, because physics. Radios emit radio waves and these can always be detected by a suitable receiver.

Note that this is *not* sniffing - that means reading the packets as they go past. The device you link to doesn't sniff - it just looks for a signal at the appropriate frequency.

(You can sniff 3G as well as detect it, of course, but no-one bothers as it is encrypted well enough that other methods of intercepting the data usually prove easier.)